# Inserting values from two list - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, sqlite

```
for item1, item2 in cartproducts, cartprices:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO orders(Product_Name, Product_Price) VALUES(?, ?);", (item1, item2, ))
    connection.commit()
```

So I'm trying to add in values from two different lists to a database using sqlite, and I'm not sure how to go about it. With this code I'm getting the error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zip:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(cartproducts, cartprices):
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO orders(Product_Name, Product_Price) VALUES(?, ?);", (item1, item2, ))
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Using zip as well as just using execute instead of executemany fixed the issue completely

Answer (score 0):

```
for item1, item2 in cartproducts, cartprices:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO orders(Product_Name, Product_Price) VALUES(?, ?);", (item1, item2 ))
    connection.commit()
```

Just do it like this. There is no need of comma after item2 thats why this error

Answer (score 0):

I don't think python supports this kind of itemA, itemB from listA, listB syntax. 
I think what you are trying to do here is have a key-value pair (Product_Name, Product_Price), which would be perfect for a dictionary! So try this:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(cartproducts, cartprices))
```

Now you can iterate through this dictionary:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():        
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO orders(Product_Name, Product_Price) VALUES(?, ?);", (k, v))

connection.commit()
```